# Решение проблемы множественных условий

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, шаблоны-проектирования

В целях самообучения пишу движок для сайта на `Node.js`. Сейчас решаю проблему множественных условий, которые возникают на уровне обработки клиентского запроса.

Придумал следующее решение: вместо того, чтобы сравнивать таким образом:

```
if (method == 'get') {
  if (headers == 'что-то') {
    // и т.п
  }

}

if (method == 'post') {
  if  (headers == 'что-то') {
    // и т.п
  }
}
```

Я просто конкатенирую нужные для разбора строки запроса, получается своеобразный ключ, который я сравниваю с заранее подготовленными ключами:

```
http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
  if (build_key_req(req) == combs_uploadFile()) {
    // Логика загрузки файла
  };
}).listen('5050', '127.0.0.1', () => {
  console.log(`start server`);
});

function build_key_req(req) {
  let { method, url } = req;
  let content_type = req.headers['content-type'];
  return method + content_type + url;
}

function combs_uploadFile() {
  let method = 'post';
  let content_type = 'multipart/form-data';
  let url = '/domain.com/upload';
  return method + content_type + url;
};
```

Не судите если есть ошибки, это просто пример.

Так вот, хочется узнать выдерживает ли такое решение критику опытных разработчиков?

Мне кажется таким образом можно просто добавлять новую логику и модифицировать код. Так как не нужно лезть в большое количество ветвлений при использовании чрезмерных `if(){}`.

Можно ли использовать такое решение в решение в реальном проекте?

Comment: так или иначе, все равно придется использовать условия. Чтобы было понятнее работать с кодом приложения - обработку каждой ветки условия можно вынести в отдельный модуль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Что такое архитектура REST?
>
> REST означает REpresentational State Transfer. REST - это
> веб-стандартная архитектура и использует протокол HTTP. Он вращается
> вокруг ресурса, где каждый компонент является ресурсом, а к ресурсу
> обращается общий интерфейс с использованием стандартных методов HTTP.
> REST был впервые представлен Роем Филдингом в 2000 году.
>
> Сервер REST просто обеспечивает доступ к ресурсам и клиентский доступ
> REST и изменяет ресурсы с использованием протокола HTTP. Здесь каждый
> ресурс идентифицируется с помощью URI / глобальных идентификаторов.
> REST использует различное представление для представления ресурса,
> такого как текст, JSON, XML, но JSON является самым популярным.
>
> **Методы HTTP:**
>
> Следующие четыре метода HTTP обычно используются в архитектуре REST.
>
> ```
>  GET - используется для обеспечения доступа только для чтения к ресурсу.
>
>  POST - используется для создания нового ресурса.
>
>  DELETE - используется для удаления ресурса.
>
>  PUT - используется для обновления существующего ресурса или создания нового ресурса.
> ```

**Как бы выгляде ваш код:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  if (headers == 'что-то') {
    // и т.п
  }
});
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  if (headers == 'что-то') {
    // и т.п
  }
});
```