# Создание очереди задач для rest api java

Tags: java, rest, очередь, task

есть десктопное приложение для обработки метеорологических данных. Вычисления достаточно трудоемкие, для получения результата к примеру пользователю необходимо ждать от 1 минуты до нескольких десятков (всё зависит от размера выборки данных пользователем).

Теперь хочу сделать данный проект в виде rest api. Однако сервер может одновременно выполнять максимум несколько одновременных запросов пользователя.

Думаю реализовать сервис по типу антиплагиата в интернете. Когда пользователь при загрузке файла, дожидается своей очереди на проверку, тем самым ограничивается нагрузка на сервер.

Каким образом лучше реализовать данную идею, возможно есть какие-то примеры?

**Upd. Нашел достаточно простой и понятный пример. Возможно кому-то пригодится)**

https://github.com/frenos/spring-mvc-async-progress

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829891/204920

Comment: Попробуйте поискать по словам реактивный рест. Касаемо одновременного выполнения ограниченного количества запросов, посмотрите по словам work in progress Олег Докука, может ваш случай